# Trying to set binary search tree node to an integer

Tags: integer, binary-search-tree, nodes

My code has two errors and I cant figure out why. Im trying to insert a node into the tree but it won't let me set the left and right nodes to the integer value. please help, this portion of my program is due on Saturday and today is Wednesday.

```
void Bst::Insert(TreeNode *&node, int item) {

if (item < node->data) {
    if (node->left == NULL)
        node->left = item;
    else
        Insert(node->left, item);
}

if (new_node->data > root->data) {
    if (node->right == NULL)
        node->right = item;
    else
        Insert(node->right, item);
}
```

}

Comment: it should say if(item > node->data)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code, I have written below c++ code of what it should look like, there might be some minor errors which you might want to investigate.

```
TreeNode * Bst::Insert(TreeNode *node, int item) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        node = (struct TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
        node->data = item;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (item < node->data) {
        node->left = Insert(node->left, item);
    }
    else if (item > node->data) {
        node->right = Insert(node->right, item);
    }
    return node;
}
```

I have edited the changes that i think might work, you may also want to include malloc.h in the headers.

Comment: i tried the code you provided and It has one error that came up. It says that "node = new Treenode();" needs a type specifier. I have no idea what type it would be, maybe int or bool?

Comment: How have you delcared your node, can you paste more code, it would be tough to debug without it.

Comment: "tree = new Bst();" i how the tree is declared in the main function. The root is declared as "TreeNode* root;" in the header file and the insert method is called by using "tree->Insert(20);" in main. Is that enough?

Comment: It's still not enough to debug, could you paste your code here : http://ideone.com/ and give the link

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to look at all of this, I am very thankful

Comment: I am posting a small code snippet without the Bst class so that you can see how the insert works, you can modify it for you code, as your code is too large to understand : http://ideone.com/ETlPbk